# SQL server temporary tables vs cursors

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, temp-tables

In SQL Server stored procedures when to use temporary tables and when to use cursors. which is the best option performance wise?

Comment: Neither if you can help it.  SQL is SET based, and can generally handle the situations most use temp tables and/or cursors for.

Comment: Why not CTE? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx

Comment: Can you clarify a bit here?  Using temporary tables vs using cursors is a bit like apples and oranges.  Temporary tables vs table variables would be a more appropriate comparison.

Comment: If I have a stored procedure which runs a bunch of set based operations, and I want to run it for say 100 different companies in my database. I think it's ok to either cursor over the 100, or use a temp table to iterate through the 100.  Is there any difference between the two in this situation?  I had though cursors used a table variable behind the scenes so it wouldn't make much difference.  Does it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If ever possible **avoid** cursors like the plague. SQL Server is **set-based** - anything you need to do in an RBAR (row-by-agonizing-row) fashion will be slow, sluggish and goes against the basic principles of how SQL works.

Your question is very vague - based on that information, we cannot really tell what you're trying to do. But the main recommendation remains: whenever possible (and it's possible in the vast majority of cases), use set-based operations `- SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT` and joins - don't force your procedural thinking onto SQL Server - that's not the best way to go.

So if you can use set-based operations to fill and use your temporary tables, I would prefer that method over cursors every time.

Answer (score 9):

Cursors work row-by-row and are extremely poor performers. They can in almost all cases be replaced by better set-based code (not normally temp tables though)

Temp tables can be fine or bad depending on the data amount and what you are doing with them. They are not generally a replacement for a cursor.

Suggest you read this:
http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Cursors_and_How_to_Avoid_Them

Answer (score 1):

I believe SARAVAN originally made the comparison between cursors and temp tables because many times you are confronted with a situation where using a temp table with an identity column and a @counter variable can be used to scroll/navigate through a data set much like one in a cursor.

In my experience, using the temp table (or table variable) scenario can help me get the job done 95% of the time and is faster than the typically slow cursor.